# Select show hide div after specific values input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm basically trying to

1. Show upload div when status input valued="Tidak aktif"
2. Hide upload div when status input valued ="Aktif"

This is my code

```
<h2>EDIT STATUS PEGAWAI</h2>

<?php 
    $ambildata = $koneksi -> query ("SELECT * FROM diniyah WHERE ID ='$_GET[id]'");
    $pecahdata = $ambildata -> fetch_assoc();

    echo "<pre>" ;
    print_r($pecahdata);
    echo "</pre>";
 ?>
<h2>GANTI STATUS PEGAWAI : </h2>
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="STATUS" id="STATUS">
        <option value="Aktif">AKTIF</option>
        <option value="Tidak Aktif">TIDAK AKTIF</option>

    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
        <input type="file" name="uploaddiniyah" class="form-control">

            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="ubah">Konfirmasi</button>
    </div>
    
 </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Tidak Aktif'])){
    include'upload.php';
}else{
    include'home.php';
}
    
?>



 <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['ubah'])) {
        $uploaddiniyah = true;
        $namafoto = $_FILES ['uploaddiniyah']['name'];
        $lokasifoto = $_FILES ['uploaddiniyah']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($lokasifoto, "../fotodokumen/".$namafoto);
        //jk foto dirubah
        $koneksi->query("UPDATE diniyah SET status='$_POST[STATUS]' WHERE ID='$_GET[id]'");
        $update_gambar=mysqli_query($koneksi,"UPDATE diniyah SET uploaddiniyah='$namafoto' WHERE ID='$_GET[id]'");

        echo "<div class='alert alert-info'> Data Tersimpan</div>";
    }

  ?>
```

Is there a mistake on my code?

Comment: You're selecting the wrong POST, it's returning null so I assume you keep getting home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic js for do that like:

```js
let status = document.getElementById('STATUS');
let upload = document.getElementById('upload');
status.onchange = function()
{
  if(this.value === "Tidak Aktif"){
    upload.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    upload.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="STATUS" id="STATUS">
        <option value="Aktif">AKTIF</option>
        <option value="Tidak Aktif">TIDAK AKTIF</option>
</select>
    <div class="form-group" id='upload' style="display:none;">
        <input type="file" name="uploaddiniyah" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! its work, but i cant save my upload file afterwards looks like on my $namafoto and $lokasifoto has undefined index which is : uploaddiniyah

Comment: if is not hide or you mean when is hide don't work?

Comment: It is shown when status selected to "tidak aktif" But apparently the upload file not going to directory nor on the database.

Comment: its done thanks for the time! Simone. Hope you have a nice day